# Advice on implementing odata for non-EF entities in asp webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

We are planning to use oData as a entity standard for rest api layer.   The data provided by web api are taken from various subsystems and layers of cache(memcache) involved.  My fear is how the basic entity model without EF can support the oData implementation of pagination and filtering.   I want the ability to restrict the retrieval record limit at the underlying susbsytem level not at the api controller level.  Any pointers would be useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a blog post on doing OData querying over non-IQueryable backends. I have picked HQL as the target query language. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx

That should help you to understand how easy it is to support OData queries using web API.

Comment: Thanks.   I followed the link and found the ODataQueryOptions is the one to tackle from my code.   I agree with your blog on creating a IQueryable wrapper is outside of the budget. I am not able to find the ODataQueryOptions class  (using vs2010 with framework 4.0 ).  Searched in Microsoft.Data.OData dll.

Comment: You need to install this package - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/